# NSNotificationCenter observer doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I am trying to post a notification as follows:

```
  NSNotificationCenter .defaultCenter() .postNotificationName("name", object: nil)
```

from within a function of viewControllerA

then in ViewControllerB in `viewDidLoad`

```
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "doSomething:", name:"name", object: nil)
```

But the `doSomething:` is never called!

any ideas?

Comment: You need to `addObserver` first,then `postNotificationName`.

Comment: @Leo I'm sorry I don't understand. where should I addObserver (in my ViewControllerA? and then in the same ViewControllerA postNotification?

Comment: I mean the moment you post a notification,there should already a observer in memory.

Comment: Basically, the `addObserver()` call must happen **before** the call to `postNotificationName()`.

Comment: oh I see. yes you are right

Answer (score 3):

Here's what the code should like in your two controllers.

In the subscribing/listening **ViewController**:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "doSomething:", name: "name", object: nil)
}

func doSomething(notification: NSNotification) {
    print("Notification was posted.")
}
```

In the publishing/posting **ViewController**:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("name", object: nil)
}
```

If it's not working, it might be due to your app's architecture:

- Are both ViewControllers currently loaded in memory?
- Is the observer added before the notification is sent?

Comment: this is exactly how i have it but apparently the observer is not loaded BEFORE the posting... that would be a problem as my viewControllerB only comes to life after I want the post to be sent... not sure how to deal with this

Comment: NSNotification might not be the right mechanism for what you want to achieve then. Why not just segue to ViewControllerB at the appropriate time (and pass it some objects/values if necessary) instead of sending the notification?

Comment: You need to rework your architecture such that both view controllers are in memory, or create some class that connects the two and performs whatever task that needs to be performed. Without more information, it would be very hard to give advice. 

As your main question has been answered, feel free to mark the answer as *correct* so future visitors to this post can benefit from this conversation. 

Feel free to reply with more information, or post another question on SO to get assistance in solving the architectural issue that you have.

Comment: you are absolutely right. I only needed to pass my values in a different way. I feel @Leo correctly answered my question in his comments but pointing out that the observer needs to be in memory BEFORE the post!